# What is the full definition of the head position “inferior limits” rule for Ordinal Turing Machines?

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability, ordinals

I cannot seem to find a full, unambiguous definition of the “inferior limits” rule for Ordinal Turing Machines [Ordinal Turing Machines](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502264) in case of how to determine the head position at limit ordinal time.

The linked source only contains the following information:

> If the head is for example moving linearly towards a limit location, say $H(s_0 + i) = h_0 + i$ for $i < \lambda$, we will have $H(s_0 + \lambda) = h_0 + \lambda.$

Question: what is the full list of properties such that if a particular pair of ordinals $(\tau, t)$ satisfies all of these properties, the head position at limit ordinal time $t$ is equal to $\tau$?

Comment: It appears to me that the definition of $H(t)$ for limit ordinals $t$ is in **Definition** $\bf{2}$$(e)$ on page $6$ of the PDF to which you linked: $$\begin{align*}H(t)&=\liminf_{\substack{s\to t\\S(s)=S(t)}}H(s)\\&=\lim_{\substack{s\to t\\S(s)=S(t)}}\inf_{\substack{s\le u<t\\S(s)=S(u)}}H(u)\\&=\sup_{\substack{s<t\\S(s)=S(t)}}\inf_{\substack{s\le u<t\\S(s)=S(u)}}H(u)\end{align*}$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: thank you very much, this is more readable. Can you please post similarly explained formulas for $T(t)$ and $S(t)$?

Comment: @lyricallywicked: I’ve added explanations for $T(t)$ and $S(t)$ and put everything into an answer, since it’s too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Definition** $\bf{2}$$(e)$ on page $6$ of the PDF to which you linked defines the tape content $T(t)$, state $S(t)$, and head position $H(t)$ at limit $t$. The state is the most straightforward:

$$\begin{align*}
S(t)&=\liminf_{r\to t}S(r)\\
&=\lim_{r\to t}\inf_{r\le s<t}S(s)\\
&=\sup_{r<t}\inf_{r\le s<t}S(s)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Recall that the states are simply natural numbers. This just says that $S(t)$ is the smallest state that occurs cofinally in the sequence $\langle S(r):r<t\rangle$, if there is one; otherwise $S(t)$ defaults to $0$.

The tape content is a binary vector with a component $T(t)_\xi$ for each ordinal $\xi$, and it is defined very similarly at limit ordinals: for each ordinal $\xi$,

$$\begin{align*}
T(t)&=\liminf_{r\to t}T(r)\\
&=\lim_{r\to t}\inf_{r\le s<t}T(s)\\
&=\sup_{r<t}\inf_{r\le s<t}T(s)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Because $T$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$, this boils down to saying that if the sequence $\langle T(r):r<t\rangle$ is eventually constant with value $b$, then $T(t)=b$, and otherwise $T(t)$ defaults to $0$.

Finally,

$$\begin{align*}
H(t)&=\liminf_{\substack{s\to t\\S(s)=S(t)}}H(s)\\
&=\lim_{\substack{s\to t\\S(s)=S(t)}}\inf_{\substack{s\le u<t\\S(s)=S(u)}}H(u)
\\&=\sup_{\substack{s<t\\S(s)=S(t)}}\inf_{\substack{s\le u<t\\S(s)=S(u)}}H(u)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Here we don’t look at the entire sequence $\langle H(s):s<t\rangle$, but only at the subsequence indexed by those $s<t$ such that $S(s)=S(t)$, i.e., those times at which the machine was in the same state.

Comment: I am not sure that my interpretation of the notion of "infimum" is correct... Consider two programs. 1. A program that always moves to the right; 2. A program that writes 0101 to cells $C_0 \ldots C_3$, returns to $C_1$, writes 1001 to cells $C_1 \ldots C_4$, returns to $C_1$, writes 10001 to cells $C_1 \ldots C_5$ etc. In case 1, each cell is visited finitely many times; in case 2, each cell except $C_0$ is visited infinitely many times, but there exists a cell indexed by 1 which looks like infimum . How to determine the value of $H(\omega)$ for these two programs? [1/2]

Comment: It seems that $H(\omega) = \omega$ for the first program and $H(\omega) = 1$ for the second program, but I cannot prove this because the notion of _infimum_ is unclear to me... [2/2]

Comment: @lyricallywicked: It does depend on the state, but if the state remains constant, you’re right. You’re also right in the second case if $S(u)=S(t)$ for infinitely many of the occasions when it revisits $C_1$.

Comment: But why? How did you find two infima (I am only interested in infima here, not suprema)? What definition of infimum did you use?

Comment: @lyricallywicked: I take the paper at its word that it’s talking about the [limit inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior).

Comment: I need one clarification: consider a variant of the second program where $S(u)=S(t)$ for infinitely many cells, not only for $C_1$. Is it true that $H(\omega)=1$ for this program?

Comment: @lyricallywicked In case the word "infimum" is confusing you, in the context of some set of ordinals you can replace it with "minimum" (but the two words are different in the context of a subset of real numbers).

Comment: @lyricallywicked: That’s my understanding.

Comment: What does the term "occurs cofinally" (I have also seen "cofinally often") mean?

Comment: @lyricallywicked: If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, a subset $S\subseteq\{\xi:\xi<\alpha\}$ is cofinal in $\alpha$ if for each $\beta<\alpha$ there is a $\xi\in S$ such that $\beta\le\xi$. Any infinite subset of $\omega$ is cofinal in $\omega$, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In infinite time, one is often is concerned with behaviour on limits. In case of OTM, the rules for "state" and "cell contents" have a relatively simple description. Consider a function $Value:\mathrm{Ord} \rightarrow n$ (for some finite ordinal $n$). Below we are really only describing a convention for determining $Value(t)$ (where $t$ is a limit). Also, in expressions below, the quantification is assumed to be over ordinals.

Suppose there is a "last time" (less than $t$) after which the function remains constant. That is, there exists some $a$ such that for all $a<b<t$ we have $Value(b)=c$, where $c$ is some constant. In that case, we always set $Value(t)=c$. But what if there is no such "last time". Meaning, for a given limit ordinal $t$, the following condition is false: $\exists a<t \,\, \forall b>a  \,[\, b<t \rightarrow \exists c \,( Value(b)=c) \, ]$. If the mentioned condition is false, then we can have to describe how to evaluate $Value(t)$.

In that case, define a predicate $R:\omega \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ as: $R(x) \equiv (\forall a<t) (\exists b>a)\,[\,b<t \wedge Value(b)=x\,]$. Next define a set of finite ordinals $A$ as $A=\{x \in \omega\,|\,R(x)\,\,is\,\,true\}$. We define $Value(t)$ to be smallest value contained in the set $A$. One other thing to note is that because the range of $Value$ function is assumed to be finite, the set $A$ will always contain at least one element.

The convention described above is what "state number" and "cell contents" in OTM follow.For example (informal description of previous paragraph), denoting the program-state at some time $x$ as $S(x)$, here is how we determine $S(t)$ (for some limit ordinal $t$). Suppose the set of states is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,.....100\}$. First check whether state-$0$ occurs for arbitrarily large ordinal values less than $t$? If it does then $S(t)=0$. It it doesn't then check whether state-$1$ occurs for arbitrarily large values less than $t$? If it does then $S(t)=1$. It it doesn't then check the same for state-$2$,$3$,$4$ and so on, until you find a value $n \leq 100$ such that state-$n$ occurs  for arbitrarily large values less than $t$. In that case, we set $S(t)=n$.

---

For determining head position, denote the head position at some time $x$ as $H(x)$. I feel that it helps a bit to write the actual definition in parts. This is what I will try to do below.

**First** determine the value $N=S(t)$, the state-number at time $t$. Note that $N$ is just an ordinary natural number. Now form a set of ordinals $X \subseteq t$ defined by $X=\{\, x\in Ord\,|\,x<t \,\wedge \, S(x)=N \}$. Note that there are arbitrarily large ordinals $<t$ that are contained in this set $X$.

For any ordinal $n<t$ define $A(n)=min\{x \,|\,x\in X \, \wedge \, n\leq x <t\}$. And now we have: $H(t)=\sup\{A(x)|x<t\}$.

---

The above is a formal description for head position. Intuitively we can use some shortcuts in number of cases. Here is one (I might try to add one or two more later).

**(1)** First check whether you can find a smallest time $T<t$ such that the head position never *decreases* from time $T$ till time $t$. In other words, let $T$ be the smallest value such that we can say that the head position is *non-decreasing* in the interval $[T,t)$. In that case just set $H(t)=\sup\{H(x)\,|\,T \leq x<t\}$. If we can't find a smallest time $T$ then we just go back to definition.

Comment: I am becoming unsure about the correctness of my understanding of how to determine the state at limit time. Question $1$: consider a machine such that state $0$ never occurs after some time, but for any ordinal $\alpha < \omega$, state $1$ occurs at some ordinal $\beta > \alpha$. Is it true that $S(\omega) = 1$? Question $2$: what does the term "occurs cofinally" mean and what is the value of $S(\omega)$ if for any state $n$ and for any ordinal $\alpha < \omega$, state $n$ occurs at some ordinal $\beta > \alpha$?

Comment: @lyricallywicked 
There is a "mistake" in my answer in the sense that there is a possibility that I haven't accounted for (regarding head position). Let me edit it first properly. (though the informal description of calculation of state number is completely fine though)

Comment: I think that the answer to Question $2$ is $S(\omega) = 0$ because $0$ is the supremum of infima in this case. But I am still unsure about what "otherwise $S(t)$ defaults to $0$" in the first answer means. How can a state default to zero at limit time if the definition of the limit inferior implies the _supremum_ of infima? Why is $0$ the supremum?

Comment: @lyricallywicked You are right. The answer is $0$ because $0$ is the smallest state which occurs for arbitrarily large values less than $\omega$. Also, sorry for the wrong description of head position. I have removed it for now (I was trying to simplify by dividing into cases but made some mistakes ..... I will re-post that part properly later).

Comment: Yes, for a given limit value $t$, if $S(x)=0$ isn't true for arbitrarily large values  $x<t$ then $S(t)=0$ will definitely be false. We will have $S(t)=a$ where $a$ is some natural number such that $a \neq 0$.

Comment: @lyricallywicked You wrote: "what is the value of $S(\omega)$ if for any state $n$ and for any ordinal $\alpha<\omega$, state $n$ occurs at some **finite** ordinal $\beta>\alpha$?" I have added the "finite" in bold because it seems that this is what you wanted to say in your first comment (below my answer).

Comment: I skipped the word "finite" deliberately because I was asking about the state at limit time $\omega$. For the sake of generality, Question $2$ can be reformulated as follows: given an arbitrary limit ordinal $\gamma$, what is the value of $S(\gamma)$ if for any state $n$ and for any ordinal $\alpha < \gamma$, state $n$ occurs at some ordinal $\beta > \alpha$, where $\beta < \gamma$? My understanding is that the answer is $0$ because $0$ is the supremum of infima (the inferior limit) in this case.

Comment: "My understanding is that the answer is 0" ..... this is correct